# js upload function?

Tags: javascript, upload, chatroom

Is there a built in function in js to upload data to a server?

I have this online chat I have just started building and I have the text input and so far it saves the data and you can chat with yourself. What i really want is to upload it to a server so it can be downloaded.

Comment: AJAX is what you are looking for

Comment: (Just curious, how would SO comments or Google Chat or .. work as they do otherwise? Using a library -- jQuery is popular, and it provides solid "AJAX" support -- can make the task much simpler, as does using standard formats like JSON. If the server is on another domain, then CORS or JSONP or similar will also need to be investigated.)

Answer (score 0):

Look into AJAX, it allows you to send data asynchronously to a server. It helps to have a knowledge of how HTTP works (it'll help you understand it better), but it's not strictly necessary :)